# Ubuntu 22 / Netplan automatically adds default route rule when changing interfaces, preventing internet access on the other interface

Tags: networking, server, ethernet, netplan

I am trying to configure a server with 2 ethernet ports to work on different subnets.
I have Port 1, connecting to network 0, which at the moment is also my source of internet access. And then I have port 2, connecting to the router for network 1, which has no internet access.

The problem I'm having is that if I take the cable from port 1, and move that to the router to supply internet access to the router for network 1, a new default route rule seems to get added. (Eventually I'll have both ports connected simultaneously, and traffic flowing to/from each port/network simultaneously)

```
alan@afs:~$ ip route show
default via 192.168.3.1 dev eno1 proto static metric 11 
default via 192.168.0.1 dev enp0s25 proto dhcp src 192.168.0.233 metric 100
```

If I delete the top rule, then the first port/0 network works properly. However after swapping the cables this rule gets reapplied for some reason.

If I take the cable from the router and move it back to port 1, the rules stay the same, and I am unable to get internet access as it still tries to use the other interface. I can still ssh into the system using this port though.

I'm assuming I have something within netplan or my routing policy configured incorrectly but I'm not really sure what, as it works as each port does work correctly before swapping the cable around between interfaces.

Any help would be appreciated, I'm still learning quite a bit.

My netplan config:

```
network:
   version: 2
   renderer: networkd
   ethernets:
      enp0S25:
         dhcp4: false
         addresses: [192.168.0.233/24]
         routes:
            - to: 0.0.0.0/0
              via: 192.168.0.1
              metric: 1
            - to: 0.0.0.0/0
              via: 192.168.0.1
              table: 1
         nameservers:
           search: [WORKGROUP]
           addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
         routing-policy:
            - from: 192.168.0.233/24
              table: 1

      eno1:
         dhcp4: false
         addresses:
         - 192.168.3.10/24
         nameservers:
            addresses: [8.8.8.8,1.1.1.1]
            search: [WORKGROUP]
         routes:
            - to: 0.0.0.0/0
              via: 192.168.3.1
              metric: 11
            - to: 0.0.0.0/0
              via: 192.168.3.1
              table: 11
         routing-policy:
            - from: 192.168.3.1/24
              table: 11
```

Edit: The other question I have is, is this even the best way to do this? I change ethernet ports frequently for testing, and will need access to both networks simultaneously often as well. However if there is only internet access on one interface, how would I direct traffic externally through the correct interface that has it at the time?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the block

```
         routes:
            - to: 0.0.0.0/0
              via: 192.168.0.1
              metric: 1
            - to: 0.0.0.0/0
              via: 192.168.0.1
              table: 1
```

to

```
         routes:
            - to: default
              via: 192.168.0.1
```

I also don't get what this block does

```
         nameservers:
            addresses: [8.8.8.8,1.1.1.1]
            search: [WORKGROUP]
         routes:
            - to: 0.0.0.0/0
              via: 192.168.3.1
              metric: 11
            - to: 0.0.0.0/0
              via: 192.168.3.1
              table: 11
         routing-policy:
            - from: 192.168.3.1/24
              table: 11
```

If you only need to access the subnetwork "192.168.3.0/24" and that you will never use it to access internet or other network, just remove the block above.

Basically change your file to look like this

```
network:
   version: 2
   renderer: networkd
   ethernets:
      enp0S25:
         dhcp4: false
         addresses: [192.168.0.233/24]
         routes:
            - to: default
              via: 192.168.0.1
         nameservers:
           search: [WORKGROUP]
           addresses: [8.8.8.8,8.8.4.4]
      eno1:
         dhcp4: false
         addresses:
         - 192.168.3.10/24
```

Edit - Current config:

```
network:
   version: 2
   renderer: networkd
   ethernets:
      enp0S25:
         dhcp4: true
         routes:
         - to: default
           via: 191.168.0.1
      eno1:
         dhcp4: false
         addresses:
         - 192.168.3.10/24
         routes:
         - to: 0.0.0.0/24
           via: 192.168.3.1
```

Comment: Thanks.

My intention was to be able to access the internet from both interfaces. At the very least, internet needs to be accessible via the enp0s25 interface, and this interface will also be used to connect to the server via ssh. The eno1 interface will be either be used to serve a pxe server or NAS share by any devices on the other subnet.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared two default routes on each interface. On `eno1`, you declare a routing policy, but only one of the two routes is set to use that routing policy.  What you want is:

```
     routes:
        - to: 0.0.0.0/0
          via: 192.168.3.1
          table: 11
     routing-policy:
        - from: 192.168.3.1/24
          table: 11
```

There is no need for setting a metric.